# Identify mip map levels by coloring different screen areas in GLSL

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, hlsl, mipmaps

I don't wish to bombard this post with code. I've got a main file, fragment shader and a vertex shader file.

I need to know the steps that I should take to color the screen according to mipmap level? I.e. where the loop should go that asks for mipmap level, then sets colour accordingly. I don't know where to implement this or how, a simple example would suffice many thanks.

Comment: Maybe I'm just dumb, but I can't tell what you're trying to do. Do you want to manually change the mipmaps so that each mipmap has a different color? Or do you want to figure out which mipmap level is being used in the fragment shader?

Comment: Honestly I don't know, I've been given a program and one of my tasks is to "5. Identify the different Mip Map levels by colouring the regions of the screen differently. "

Answer (score 1):

You should create a texture with a different color for every level, and then retrieve that color in your fragment program. It might also be possible to compute it using `dFdx(texcoord.x)` and `dFdy(texcoord.y)`.

Comment: Thanks, you make it sound easy. However could you be more specific? I'm a noob

Comment: float mip = log2(max(dFdx(Texcoord.x)*texSizeX,dFdy(Texcoord.y)*texSizeY));

Answer (score 1):

Like tibur said, an easy way to do this is to use a debug texture that have a different color for every level as seen [here](http://www.geeks3d.com/20100311/tips-mipmap-levels-debugging-with-a-dds-debug-texture/).

Now if you need to compute the mipmap level by hand (usually a floating point value), this is another story since you will need derivatives, but [this](http://mollyrocket.com/forums/viewtopic.php?t=826&sid=40a1f88878d8044cee5c2587e21a994f) should put you on track.

Comment: Thanks for that. I need to do this the easy way, if there is such a thing. But I don't have a clue, my lecturer is rubbish and I can't find any material that just makes sense. e.g. "Put X command in Y function"

Answer (score 1):

http://http.developer.nvidia.com/GPUGems2/gpugems2_chapter28.html

This GPU Gems 2 article implements something like what you want.

Comment: Those two pictures sum up what I'm trying to do. I just need some generic code that does it.....